# Multiple Indexes and graphs in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
Species      POAPRA   AGGREP
R2             1        2  
D1             5        8
D2             4        5
```

and I want to make a graph of it using the following code:

```
ax=df.plot(title='Invasive Species')
ax.set_xlabel('Departure Level')
ax.set_ylabel('Percent Occurance')
```

which yields

[image]

The problem is I would like to have the x-axis show R1, D1 and D2 instead of 0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5 and 2.0.  I am pretty sure I need to set the first column as an index but since I would have multiple indexes I am not sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just `set_index` to `Species` before plotting.

```
ax=df.set_index('Species').plot(title='Invasive Species')
ax.set_xlabel('Departure Level')
ax.set_ylabel('Percent Occurance')
```

[image]